# AngularJS : access deferred promise from new template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise, angularjs-factory

I'm new to angular and LOVE it...coming from a 10 yr PHP background there is a lot of new terms for me. 
Here is what I would like to-do, not sure if it's possible, if yes, not sure how. I have created a list of properties and **that part works fine**. the list shows limited details of each property and all the details are available for a detailed view.

So my question is how to access that data by id without hitting the DB again and showing in a new template for a detailed view?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
propApp.controller('propertyCrtl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $timeout, getProperty ) {

  var promise = getProperty.getList();
  promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.list = data.data.listings;
    $scope.id = $routeParams.prop_id;
    $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
    $scope.entryLimit = 20; //max no of items to display in a page
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    //console.log(data.data.listings);
  })
```

and the service

```
propApp.service('getProperty', function($http, $q){

var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.get('wp-content/themes/wp-angular-theme/ajax/getProperty.php')
.then(function(data){
  deferred.resolve(data);
});

this.getList = function(){
  return deferred.promise;
}

this.getById = function(id){
  return deferred.promise;
} 

})
```

Any help would be appreciated...Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `getByid` method like this.

```
this.getById = function(id){
   var def = $q.defer();
   deferred.promise.then(function(data){
      //find the matching list
      for (var i = 0;i <data.data.listings.length;i++) {
         if (data.data.listings[i].id == id) {
            def.resolve(data.data.listings[i]);    
            return;
         }
      }
      //Reject the promise here because we didn't find the matching id
      def.reject();
   });   
   return def;
}
```

**Edit:**

Since the `list` is available in the `$scope` object you get can get the list details from `$scope.list` itself.

Controller

```
propApp.controller('propertyCrtl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $timeout, getProperty ) {

  getProperty.getList()
  .then(function(data){
    $scope.list = data.data.listings;
    $scope.id = $routeParams.prop_id;
    $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
    $scope.entryLimit = 20; //max no of items to display in a page
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    //console.log(data.data.listings);
  });

  $scope.getListDetails = function (id) {
    for (var i = 0;i <$scope.list.length;i++) {
             if ($scope.list[i].id == id) {
                return $scope.list[i];
             }
          }
    return null;
  }
});
```

Service

```
propApp.service('getProperty', function($http, $q){

  this.getList = function(){
    return $http.get('wp-content/themes/wp-angular-theme/ajax/getProperty.php')
  }

});
```

Comment: why we need to create extra promise?

Comment: I know it is not required because `$http` gives us the promise. But I think OP is trying to maintain that promise so that he can get the list or list details again without making a new request.

Comment: Actually since the list is already available in the `$scope` we get the list details from `$scope.list` itself.

Comment: you are talking about controller level..could you explain how can he avoid second request..?

Comment: OP mentioned that all the details are already available so we dont need second call.

Comment: Thank you! I can follow the logic...
Something I'm not clear on. How do I access the new template or display in a new template? I would think if opened a new template with the same controller it would just hit the DB again which defeats the purpose?

Comment: You can have a partial view and show it only when required.

Answer (score 0):

Don't seems like you are doing any modification or validation with the data then  there is no need of creating new promise. `$http.get` returns promise itself, You can utilize the `$http` object promise itself.

**Service**

```
propApp.service('getProperty', function($http, $q) {

    this.getList = function() {
        return $http.get('wp-content/themes/wp-angular-theme/ajax/getProperty.php');
    }

    this.getById = function(id) {
        return $http.get('wp-content/themes/wp-angular-theme/ajax/getProperty.php?id=' + id);
    }

})
```